Efficient search of Neo4j relationships by property value
In Neo4j, I need to find all relationships with a given property value, independently on the relationship type:
WITH ["1651365", "1188654", "1151147", ...] AS relIds
MATCH ()-[r]->() WHERE r.myId IN relIds
RETURN TYPE(r) AS type, properties ( r ) AS props;

This query works, but it's very slow. If I profile it, I see it's based on a full scan (of 14M relationships).
The problem is there is no way to define an index on all the relationship types (I can do the same with a list of types and the engine will use indexes defined for myId).
Is there a solution? When using elementId(), the engine does a seek operation and it's very fast, but the documentation discourages it (they say internal IDs are reused after deletion).

Use UNWIND on relIds. Like in line 2:  UNWIND relIds as relId then line 3 will use WHERE r.myId = relId. Goodluck

@jose_bacoy thanks, but that doesn't help, the engine still uses a scan to match r.myId = relId

You can create a fulltext index on properties of multiple relationship types. For example:
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ft_rel_myId IF NOT EXISTS FOR ()-[r:A|B|C|D|E]-() ON EACH [r.myId];

With that index, you can do a fulltext search:
WITH apoc.text.join(["1651365", "1188654", "1151147"], ' OR ') AS ft_query
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryRelationships("ft_rel_myId", ft_query) YIELD relationship, score
WHERE score = 1.0
RETURN relationship.type AS type, properties (relationship) AS props;


Thanks. I don't know the list of relation types in advance, basically, I'm querying over all the relations having that property, could I do: CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ... FOR ()-[r]->()?
Also, not sure the query will work with something like 10k IDs .

You have to specify at least one relationship type when creating the index. You can generate the rel filter for all rel types (to place after :) this way: MATCH ()-[r]->() RETURN "\" + apoc.text.join(COLLECT(DISTINCT TYPE(r)), '|') + "`" AS types`. You can try it out to see if it works for you.

Interesting, though now I'm thinking that generaring the list of types is something I could do straight on my original query, which then would become efficient without the full text index (relation IDs and types come from a previous computation). Thanks again.

I've accepted the cybersam's answer, since it's a good one for the general case (when adding the comment on how to generate the list of relation types).
I'm thinking of another approach, though:
I get the relIds from a previous query, which could also get relation types, and then the latter could be used to build a list of '|' separated types to be passed to my original query.
This way, the query becomes efficient (myId has an index for each type and Neo4j uses it).
This is an example from my real DB:
PROFILE 
WITH ["1651365", "1188654", ...]
  AS relIds
MATCH () - [r:pub_in|part_of|occ_in] -> ()
WHERE r.ondexId IN relIds
RETURN
  r.ondexId AS relId,
  TYPE(r) AS type,
  properties(r) AS props

And this is a fragment of the resulting query plan, where you can see the engine exploits indexes in single-type queries and then makes a union of them:


If I understand you correctly, you want to create an index for each relationship type on the myId property, and then change your MATCH to MATCH ()-[r:A|B|C|D]->() WHERE r.myId IN relIds, where A, B, C and D are the relationship types from a previous query. But the query planner won't know which index to scan without looking at which index has the value.

it seeks into the indexes for A, B, C and then makes a union of the results. I've already tried it and that's what the PROFILE is telling it happens. The only concern is if the list of relation types is too long.

Interesting. Can you share the bit of the profile that shows that?

@FinbarGood, I've added that to my answer (please, vote it if you like it).

Ah it does for relationships, not nodes. Nice!
